# access terraform variable from remote file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to access variable's value from remote location(file, etc.)

I read about `input variables` but still couldn't achieve what I am looking for. 
My case is to get the value of the variable from some remote file.

I tried something like below

```
terraform apply -var-file="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/..."
```

but this give error saying `no such file or directory`.

Is there any way to load values on runtime from remote location ?

*EDIT:* I am using mysql provider to create database & users. For setting the user password, I want to use some remote location where my passwords are kept (maybe a s3 file). 
PS : I saw that there is keybase available for passwords but I wanted to check if there are other ways for achievening this ?

Comment: If you're using S3 why not just use SSM parameter store or secrets manager instead? These are actually designed for storing things like database passwords instead of just being a blob in S3.

Comment: I think the file must be local, https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files

Comment: @Kthanvi did you look into my answer.

Comment: @Adiii yes! thanks for that, it helped. But apparently in my case we cannot connect to databases from local system, so I am figuring out a different way,

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to download and pass the file name to terraform apply, but you can do this with bash, This is how we do in remote server.

```
#!/bin/bash
varfile_name=terraformvar.tfvars
varfile=$(aws s3 cp s3://bucket-********/web-app/terraform/terraform_vars.tfvars ./$varfile_name)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    terraform apply -var-file=$varfile_name
else
    echo "failed to download file from s3"
fi
```